# retrieving the list from the object in java

Tags: java

I have a POJO as shown below

```
public class RrokerInvoice  {
private long RrokerId;
private double initialAmount;
private transient List<RrokerInvoiceLineItem> lineItems; //**** containg the list also of another pojo type *****

// and the corresponding setters & getters 

)
```

now in some other piece of code i am getting the object populated as shown below

```
 RrokerInvoice RrokerInvoice1 = readinginvoiceimpl.findHeaderRowNumber(workbook, 0, RrokerInvoiceLineItemList, RrokerInvoice , RrokerIdlong );
```

so as you can see that above i am getting the values populated in `RrokerInvoice1` object which is of  `RrokerInvoice`  pojo type and this object also contain the list also  now so from this object `RrokerInvoice1` i want to retrieve that list  so i have created an list as shown below

```
 List<RrokerInvoiceLineItem> retrieveitems = new List<RrokerInvoiceLineItem> ;
```

Please advise how to retrieve the list from `brokerinvoie1` object and fetch in the above created list.

Comment: I don't get your question clearly. you want to get the List RrokerInvoiceLineItem in RrokerInvoice1?! Then add all that list to your retrieveitems?!

Comment: Any reason of making `lineItems` making transient?

Comment: I did not understand question properly. If you are looking for getting lineItems list, write a public method in RrokerInvoice to return the list. public List<RrokerInvoiceLineItem> getLineItems(){return lineItems;}

Comment: `// and the corresponding setters & getters` Use one of these

Answer (score 0):

Get `RrokerInvoiceLineItem` list from `RrokerInvoice1` obj.

```
RrokerInvoice RrokerInvoice1 = readinginvoiceimpl.findHeaderRowNumber(workbook, 0, 
                                RrokerInvoiceLineItemList, RrokerInvoice , RrokerIdlong );

List<RrokerInvoiceLineItem> retrieveitems = RrokerInvoice1.getLineItems();
```

Note : I assume you have `getLineItems()` getter method in your pojo.

I would like to suggest you to give better naming convention for your object. At least start with lower case. Refer [Google Java Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
// RrokerInvoice.java 
public List<RrokerInvoiceLineItem> getLineItems(){
     return lineItems;
}
// in caller class
 List<RrokerInvoiceLineItem> retrieveitems = RrokerInvoice1.getLineItems();
```

I would like to post this answer as comment but comment is not readable and hence posted as answer.